# Parsing couchdb query result using json in Python

Tags: python, couchdb

I am a getting query result from couchdb `emit` function in python as follows:

`<Row id=u'c0cc622ca2d877432a5ccd8cbc002432', key=u'eric', value={u'_rev': u'1-e327a4c2708d4015e6e89efada38348f', u'_id': u'c0cc622ca2d877432a5ccd8cbc002432', u'email': u'yap', u'name': u'eric'}>`

How do I parse the content of value item as:

`{u'_rev': u'1-e327a4c2708d4015e6e89efada38348f', u'_id': u'c0cc622ca2d877432a5ccd8cbc002432', u'email': u'yap', u'name': u'eric'}`

using **json**?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "parsing the contents using json". The data should already be parsed and you can refer to any attributes by doing something like `row.value["_id"]` where `row` is the name of the variable referencing the `Row` object.

Answer (score 0):

The value is already converted to a python dictionary. So, if you need to change it to a JSON string just use json.loads, otherwise you can access the key with row.key and value attributes with row.value['some_attribute'].